# Using MVVM with windows mobile development

Tags: mvvm, compact-framework, windows-ce

Im working on developing an application for a barcode device, which runs on windows CE 5.0.

Ive been looking at MVVM pattern for developing apps for desktop using C# .NET and wanted to find out if I can actually develop a smart device app using MVVM.

If yes can someone point to some resources, I couldnt find any.

If not should I just go ahead with a windows form application??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVVM is just a pattern that uses data binding.  You can create an app that uses it or one that doesn't.  In fact you can create one that's a hybrid and uses it in some places.  Create Form s and call them Views, then bind the UI elements to properties in other classes you call "ViewModels" and you're most of the way there. You could use MVC or MVP as patterns as alternatives, or you could actually mix them all in one app.

If you're asking if the CF supports databinding UI elements, the answer is yes.  Or are you actually asking if there is some "formalized" MVVM framework for the Compact Framework?

Comment: I wanted to know if there is a formalized framework for CF like the MVVM Light which I can make use of instead of writing everything on own

Comment: The databinding.. Can I use xaml views and bind them?

Comment: So you want XAML, not MVVM?  No, XAML is not supported - well not from managed code anyway.

Comment: I was looking for MVVM.. XAML is just a question I had.. Ill probabaly work with it like you suggested